# Default Opp Name on Create - Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am trying to have an Opportunity Name defaulted on the initial Create screen from the parent Account. The use case is to have the Opp Name populated with something generic, and On Save, a workflow updates the name with a concatenation. But what I've read the only way to get a default text value on the "Create" screen is with a VF page, and then mapping the VF page to the "New Opportunity" button...the page looks perfect, but the Opp name is still blank, and I have a workflow that populates the Opp Name.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, ['Opportunity.Name'='Test'], true)}" />
```

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, ['Opportunity.Name'='Derp'], true)}"
/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

you do not need Opportunity.name just Name should do the trick:

**update : can you try opp3 = 'Test'**

```
  <apex:page standardController="Opportunity"
        action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, [opp3 ='Test'], true)}" />
```

How do you identify the name of a field

For finding standard / custom field Id you can use the below method.

Step 1: Open chrome and click on new button on the opportunity.

Step 2: Right click on the opportunity name field and choose "Inspect Element"

The console will highlight the name and Id of the field.

[image]

Comment: Still blank unfortunately

Comment: @TNSalesforceGuru do you have record types on oppty?

Comment: No it's a brand new blank dev org just spun up yesterday

Comment: @TNSalesforceGuru look at the update

Comment: Wow. It's perfect. How did that fix it?? Thanks for your help Rao! I chose your answer as 'Correct'

Comment: That's interesting, where does the 3 come from? Index on the fields?

Comment: @BrianMansfield opp3 is the Id used internally by salesforce, every standard field has a predefined Id.Check this blog post : http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058016777/how-to-obtain-a-field-id